# Reimplementation of UITextView and UITextField using Core Text

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uitextview, core-text, uitextinput

Is there an open source reimplementation of `UITextView` and `UITextField` using Core Text?

There's Apple's [SimpleTextInput](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleTextInput) with `SimpleCoreTextView` and `EditableCoreTextView` classes, which explicitly says:

```
     File: SimpleCoreTextView.m
 Abstract: 

 A view that draws text, reasons about layout, and manages a selection over its text range.

 IMPORTANT: Its use of CoreText is naive and inefficient, it deals only with
 left-to-right text layout, and it is by no means a good template for any text
 editor.  It is a toy implementation included only to illustrate how to bind
 the system keyboard to some pre-existing text editor.
```

In other words, it doesn't handle e.g. Arabic, and is inefficient.

What alternatives do we have for a complete implementation of an editable text field or text view, based on Core Text and `UITextInput` family of protocols?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use or refer [OmniGroup's TextEditor](https://github.com/omnigroup/OmniGroup/tree/master/Workspaces)
for implementation of an editable text field or text view, based on Core Text and `UITextInput`

Comment: From what I can see, the majority of code is in `OUIEditableFrame.m`, right? https://github.com/omnigroup/OmniGroup/blob/master/Frameworks/OmniUI/iPad/OUIEditableFrame.m -- Ouch -- that's lengthy. I won't be trying this out any time soon, but I'll accept the answer. Thanks!